# Uploading Image with Button Click

Tags: c#, javascript, image, file-upload

I have to upload image with a image button click.
I tried with the following code.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script>
    function browse() {
        document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>').click();
 }
  </script>
   </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:toolkitscriptmanager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:toolkitscriptmanager>           
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="browse();"
  ImageUrl="logo.gif" />
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
```

On image button click browse window is opened. But when i click on image and open it, that image path is not visible in the upload control textbox, like we do it normally with upload control without a imagebutton. That means upload control.Hasfile is false
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you brows the image with file uploader, path automatically comes in textbox.

No need to take extra brows or image button for it.

Brows button is bydefault given.

You can take the tutorial of file uploader with pictorial representation in following link:

http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/fileupload.html

If you want to save image, have this function in your code:

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"]; 
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength ) 
    { 
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); 
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname))); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I need to add a image and i want the browse window to open. which I did, but it is not getting uploaded

Comment: @SandraDsouza plz have above function in code if you want to save that image

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for image button :

OnClientClick="browse(); return false;"